# Xcode 7 bundle identifier without paid developer license

Tags: python, ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I was told that I could build apps onto my iOS device without a paid developer license without iOS 7. I'm compiling a pythonista script using the template provided. If this is the case, how do I get a bundle identifier to put my app on my iPad?

When I try to build the app onto my iPad, I get 
[image: this error]

If I press "Fix Issue", I am told that 
[image]

Without a paid developer license, how do I get a bundle identifier for my app?

Comment: There are a few tutorials on the web showing how to do this.

Comment: Can you point me to any?

Comment: The ones I found tell me to go to the iOS provisioning portal, which tells me access unavailable

Comment: See: [Launch Your App on Devices Using Free Provisioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3). I found this with 2 minutes of googling.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I just had to use com.example!

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Posting of just links is discouraged, it would just get down voted.

Comment: Ok. Well, thanks anyway.